# Can I use Java code inside the @Calculation annotation in OpenXava?

Tags: java, openxava

Does the @Calculation annotation support Java code? For example, does the next code work?

```
LocalDate startDate;

@Calculation("startDate.plusDays(400)")
LocalDate endDate;
```

Otherwise, how can I implement the above case?

Answer (score 0):

In @Calculation you can only use basic arithmetic expressions. If you want to use Java, create a calculated property, that is, just define a getter without field and setter, like this:

```
@Depends("startDate")
public LocalDate getEndDate() {
    return startDate.plusDay(400);
}
```

Note the @Depends("startDate") in order endDate would be recalculated in UI when startDate changes.